# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-webserver'

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

While spinning up the **SharePoint framework**, getting the mentioned error instead of running the gulp task which I got scaffold from the Yeoman.

Answer (score 4):

Issue was with the existance of the web server. Solution: Go to gulp location within your solution and use below..Solved!

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-webserver
```

This would be usefull..[npmjs-gulpserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver)